# UWP draw Line without XAML using events

Tags: c#, uwp, line

I'm fairly new to UWP. I'm currently developing an app which tests touchscreen integrity and functionality for that I'm recording key presses, using events made by Grid in mainpage.

Grid has a name **grid** I'm using event listeners: **Grid_pointermoved** and **Grid_PointerReleased** accordingly to get an array of path where swipe was made so I can analyze the path. This part is already made and currently works well.

**What I tried** :

Now i need to draw a line on a screen where swipe is being made. I tried to Google and find some info about it, but I was unable to find any solution on how to plot a line based on bunch of coordinates I just got from event listeners.

Also I have separate event which stops recording swipes and this event should also be able to clear screen from any lines previously made.
Since each test has different amount of lines I also cannot hard-code line objects beforehand.
Any appropriate help on how to simply draw a line without using XAML and relies on already-made events is welcome.

Comment: You already have a XAML Grid, so is there a reason why you can't use XAML lines?

Comment: I think the OP means he wants to do it in code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo for you, hope it will help you.

XAML page:

```
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        rootGrid.PointerPressed += RootGrid_PointerPressed;
        rootGrid.PointerMoved += RootGrid_PointerMoved;
        rootGrid.PointerReleased += RootGrid_PointerReleased;
        rootGrid.PointerExited += RootGrid_PointerExited;
    }

    int pointerId = -1;
    Line curLine = null;

    private void RootGrid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnComplete();
    }

    private void RootGrid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnComplete();
    }

    private void OnComplete()
    {
        // reset pointerId so that other pointers may enter live rendering mode
        pointerId = -1;
        curLine = null;
    }

    private void RootGrid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pointerPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(rootGrid);

        if (pointerId == (int)pointerPoint.PointerId)
        {
            curLine.X2 = pointerPoint.Position.X;
            curLine.Y2 = pointerPoint.Position.Y;
            curLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }

    private void RootGrid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make sure no pointer is already drawing (we allow only one 'active' pointer at a time)
        if (pointerId == -1)
        {
            var pointerPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(rootGrid);
            if (!pointerPoint.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
                return;

            curLine = new Line();
            var position = pointerPoint.Position;
            curLine.X1 = pointerPoint.Position.X;
            curLine.Y1 = pointerPoint.Position.Y;
            curLine.StrokeThickness = 1;

            rootGrid.Children.Add(curLine);

            //save pointer id so that no other pointer can ink until this one is released
            pointerId = (int)pointerPoint.PointerId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much based on this code I got it working and draws polylines quite well. Sadly implementing this code game me another headache:
while adding children to grid this somehow blocks some other functionality my app has. My app also has TCP - server functionality based on this sample code from MSDN:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets

Now if I add children to grid it blocks communication with TCP server. How can I unblock this ?

Comment: you need to add lines to gird in UI thread, and in another thread to communicate with TCP server.

Answer (score 0):

You have a collection of points, you can draw a [Ployline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Polyline) from the points and add it to the Grid.

```
private void CreatePolyline()
{
    // Initialize a new Polyline instance
    Polyline polyline = new Polyline();

    // Set polyline color
    polyline.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    // Set polyline width/thickness
    polyline.StrokeThickness = 10;

    // Initialize a point collection
    var points = new PointCollection();
    points.Add(new Point(20, 100));
    points.Add(new Point(35, 150));
    points.Add(new Point(60, 200));
    points.Add(new Point(90, 250));
    points.Add(new Point(40, 300));

    // Set polyline points
    polyline.Points = points;

    // Finally, add the polyline to layout
    grid.Children.Add(polyline);
}
```

**Alternatively,** for the purpose of testing touchscreen integrity you may use another User Control [InkCanvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/pen-and-stylus-interactions#basic-inking-with-inkcanvas), without having to draw the lines programmatically.

First, remove all the code you have done, so you have a blank Grid 'grid'.

In the designer, drag an `InkCanvas` control to 'grid'.

And enables touch functionality from code behind:

```
inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
```

That is all.

And to clear inks from the `InkCanvas`, you can simply call this in the **separate event** you mentioned,

```
inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.Clear();
```